# AS3 - Initialising Objects Dynamically

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've been trying to improve the code I use often, and was wondering if there was an easy way to achieve this.

I have a navigation class that defines the objects prior to the constructor (private var exampleScreen:ExampleScreen;).

Based on a string dependency injection for a ChangeScreenTo function (destinationScreen: String), is it possible to grab the defined screen and initialise it (exampleScreen =  new ExampleScreen();) dynamically?
Either way, does anyone have any better suggestions than this or my current solution of a switch statement?

Example Code:

```
package{
    public class ScreenController extends MovieClip {
        private var currentScreen: DisplayObject;
        //SCREENS
        private var exampleScreen1:ExampleScreen1;
        private var exampleScreen2:ExampleScreen2;
        ...
        public function ScreenController() {
            ...
        }
        public function ChangeScreenTo(desinationScreenName: String) {
            //REMOVE CURRENT SCREEN
            if (currentScreen != null) {
                removeChild(currentScreen);
                currentScreen = null;
            }
            switch (destinationScreenName) {
                case "exampleScreen1":
                    exampleScreen1 = new ExampleScreen1();
                    break;
                case "exampleScreen2":
                    exampleScreen2 = new ExampleScreen2();
                    break;
                ...
            }
            mcDestinationScreen = this[(destinationScreenName)];
            addChild(mcDestinationScreen);
            currentScreen = mcDestinationScreen;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe someone can help you but this is too abstract for me. Post some formatted code in a block so I can actually see your current implementation

Comment: So you need to instantiate a certain class depending on s string value? Anything to do with hiding other (previously opened) screens?

Comment: Code added to question.

Comment: Initializing Objects Dynamically is tricky and bad practice in OOP.
However all is possible, but You may improve Your Classes to avoid such tricky solutions. Nope?
I personally thing there's something wrong in this manner of coding.
This needs some research on the AS3 reference
Could You edit , improve Your question please?

Comment: Nice edit @NealDavis as usual!.

Comment: @SeanG if you set `currentScreen = null;` does that not cause an issue later when you say `currentScreen = mcDestinationScreen;`? Test it (ie: instead of using an `if` statement at top just set it to `null` & see if it still works 10 code lines later)

Answer (score 0):

May be this is better:

```
    public function ChangeScreenTo(desinationScreenName: String) {
        //REMOVE CURRENT SCREEN
        if (currentScreen != null) {
            removeChild(currentScreen);
            currentScreen = null;
        }
        switch (destinationScreenName) {
            case "exampleScreen1":
                currentScreen = exampleScreen1 = new ExampleScreen1();
                break;
            case "exampleScreen2":
                currentScreen = exampleScreen2 = new ExampleScreen2();
                break;
            ...
        }
        addChild(currentScreen);
    }
```